# Python scripting error (merge)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, merge

I've been trying to use this code to add a field to, merge, and sort multiple feature classes:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\TownshipsDissolved\FinalDissolved.gdb'

#Looping through dissolved feature classes, adding 'Name' field and writing
#feature class name in the added field.
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Name", "TEXT", field_length = 50)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Name") as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        row[0] = fc
        cursor.updateRow(row)


#Merging the multiple feature classes into one named OSRS_ORN_NER.
mergeOutput = r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\TownshipsDissolved\FinalDissolved.gdb\OSRS_ORN_NER'
sortOutput = r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\TownshipsDissolved\FinalDissolved.gdb\OSRS_ORN_NER_new'

arcpy.Merge_management(fcs, mergeOutput)


#Sorting by HWY_NUM_PR and replacing OSRS_ORN_NER by the sorted feature class.

arcpy.Sort_management(mergeOutput, sortOutput, [["HWY_NUM_PR", "ASCENDING"]])
```

but when I run it I get an error that says this:
[image]

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: please add this question as an edit of your previous question.

Comment: Could it be to do with your path names? Its bad practice to use & and spaces in folder names.

Comment: just for checking, what does print fcs return ? Aren't your features in a feature dataset ?

Comment: @radouxju I think it is correct to ask this as a new question rather than "as an edit of your previous question" because the earlier question already has an (accepted) answer that might become invalidated.

Comment: Please try to always include the text (not screenshots) of code and errors because that way they can be searched.

Comment: I think that Aaron's answer was good and should not be invalidated. My guess is that there is just a small problem with the ListFeatureClasses (feature dataset, special characters or something else).

Comment: I think I had everything stored in a layer, would that have been why? @radouxju

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Windows Explorer to copy `W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\TownshipsDissolved\FinalDissolved.gdb` to `C:\temp` and then try replacing:

```
r'W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\TownshipsDissolved\FinalDissolved.gdb'
```

with:

```
r'C:\temp\FinalDissolved.gdb'
```

as a test to see whether it is a problem with your pathname containing an ampersand and/or a space.